# Applying a function repeatedly to many subjects

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows,

```
> mydata
date  station  treatment  subject   par
A       a         0         R1      1.3    
A       a         0         R1      1.4    
A       a         1         R2      1.4   
A       a         1         R2      1.1    
A       b         0         R1      1.5    
A       b         0         R1      1.8     
A       b         1         R2      2.5     
A       b         1         R2      9.5    
B       a         0         R1      0.3    
B       a         0         R1      8.2    
B       a         1         R2      7.3    
B       a         1         R2      0.2    
B       b         0         R1      9.4    
B       b         0         R1      3.2    
B       b         1         R2      3.5    
B       b         1         R2      2.4 
....
```

where:

`date` is a factor with 2 levels A/B;
`station` is a factor with 2 levels a/b;
`treatment` is a factor with 2 levels 0/1;

`subject` are the replicates R1 to R20 assigned to treatment (10 to `treatment 0` and 10 to treatment 1);

and
`par` is my parameter, which is a repeated measurement of particle size for each subject at at each date and station

What i need to do is:
divide par in 10 equal bins and count the number in each bin. This has to be done in subsets of `mydata` definded by a combination of date station and subject. The final outcome has to be a daframe `myres` as follow:

```
> myres
    date  station  treatment  bin.centre  freq
    A       a         0         1.2        4 
    A       a         0         1.3        3    
    A       a         0         1.4        2 
    A       a         0         1.5        1    
    A       a         1         1.2        4    
    A       a         1         1.3        3    
    A       a         1         1.4        2     
    A       a         1         1.5        1    
    B       b         0         2.3        5   
    B       b         0         2.4        4    
    B       b         0         2.5        3    
    B       b         0         2.6        2   
    B       b         1         2.3        5   
    B       b         1         2.4        4   
    B       b         1         2.5        3   
    B       b         1         2.6        2
    ....
```

this is what i've done so far:

```
#define the number of bins
num.bins<-10

#define the width of each bins
bin.width<-(max(par)-min(par))/num.bins

#define the lower and upper boundaries of each bins
bins<-seq(from=min(par), to=max(par), by=bin.width)

#define the centre of each bins
bin.centre<-c(seq(min(bins)+bin.width/2,max(bins)-bin.width/2,by=bin.width))

#create a vector to store the frequency in each bins

  freq<-numeric(length(length(bins-1)))

 # this is the loop that counts the frequency of particles between the lower and upper boundaries
 of each bins and store the result in freq

 for(i in 1:10){
    freq[i]<-length(which(par>=bins[i] &
    par<bins[i+1]))
     }

 #create the data frame with the results
 res<-data.frame(bin.centre,res)
```

my first approach was to subset mydata manually, using `subset()`,for each combination of subject station and date, and apply the above sequence of commands for each subsets, then build the final dataframe combining each single `res` using `rbind()`, but this procedure was very convoluted and subject to the propagation of errors.
What i would like to do, is to automate the above procedure so that it calculates the binned frequency distribution for each subject. My intuition is that the best way to do this is by creating a function for estimating this particle distribution, and then applying it to each subject via a for loop. However, I am not sure of how to do this. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

thanks
matteo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a few steps using the functionality in the `plyr` package.  This allows you to split your data into the desired chunks, apply a statistic to each chunk, and combine the results.

First I set up some dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
dat <- data.frame(
    date=sample(LETTERS[1:2], n, replace=TRUE),
    station=sample(letters[1:2], n, replace=TRUE),
    treatment=sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE),
    subject=paste("R", sample(1:2, n, replace=TRUE), sep=""),
    par=runif(n, 0, 5)
)
head(dat)

  date station treatment subject       par
1    A       b         0      R2 3.2943880
2    A       a         0      R1 0.9253498
3    B       a         1      R1 4.7718907
4    B       b         0      R1 4.4892425
5    A       b         0      R1 4.7184853
6    B       a         1      R2 3.6184538
```

Now I use the function in base called `cut` to divide your par into equal sized bins:

```
dat$bin <- cut(dat$par, breaks=10)
```

Now for the fun bit.  Load package `plyr` and use the function `ddply` to split, apply and combine.  Because you want a frequency count, we can use the function `length` to count the number of times each replicate appeared in that bin:

```
library(plyr)
res <- ddply(dat, .(date, station, treatment, bin), 
  summarise, freq=length(treatment))
head(res)

  date station treatment             bin freq
1    A       a         0 (0.00422,0.501]    1
2    A       a         0   (0.501,0.998]    2
3    A       a         0      (1.5,1.99]    4
4    A       a         0     (1.99,2.49]    2
5    A       a         0     (2.49,2.99]    2
6    A       a         0     (2.99,3.48]    1
```

Comment: Also checkout the count function for a faster solution

Comment: Andrie, thanks for your help. But it does not work as i need. The function cut divides the whole par column in intervals of the same length, but this has to be done within each subject. Also in this way when it comes to the 'fun bit' i loose the null counts, whereas i need to know when in a bin there is no partilces. Finally, in the final res dataframe in column bin I need the middle value of each bin not the upper and lower limits. Sorry if haven't been clear at first place. Thanks